# Why is "Avatar: The Last Airbender" considered fantasy?

Tags: discussion

Why is Avatar: The Last Airbender considered part of the 'fantasy' genre?

**What are some examples to prove it?**

Comment: Doesn't "controls elements with powers received from spirits" count? In any case, you'd probably have trouble getting users on this site to agree where fantasy begins and sci-fi ends.

Comment: It has supernatural elements (which disqualifies it as a non-fiction), its not describing beliefs of any religion (so its not a myth); technology presented is described briefly and its not a focus of the story (which rather disqualifies it as SF), it has no scary elements (so its not a horror). It COULD be described as a "magical realism", but then we have magical word, not lets say medieval Japan.

Comment: Um, that thing where people throw strange elemental magic at each other and have various weird fantasy powers?

Comment: Titular character has glowing arrow tattoos on his head and body. Has survived quasi-cryogenically for ~100 years. [Eats a s*** load of food](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13089/21267). His best friend's girlfriend is literally the Moon... Yeah, nothing fantastical about it.

Answer (score 6):

Off the top of my head, there are a number of elements (pun intended) that place Avatar firmly into the "fantasy" category

- Fantastical [other-worldly setting](https://external-preview.redd.it/D6COo3YmmcBYv5zwCHMdZO4kUjpczWZjNc-Td7cHH20.jpg?auto=webp&v=enabled&s=f6fcca57639db88e128a966c61fe50a1dc66b3e2).
- The titular character is capable of a wide variety of [elemental magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdHvPfgoF8U)
- The titular character can commune with a "[spirit-world](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KhBcABRI1c)" containing demons
- The titular character is a reincarnation of prior characters
- Many characters are capable of [elemental magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1EnW4kn1kg) which seems to be strengthened/weakened by the presence or absence of appropriate talismans such as the moon spirit fish and a passing comet.
- [Flying bison](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/avatar/images/8/82/Appa_soaring.png/revision/latest?cb=20140117221705) (and flying other creatures)
- Hybrid creatures, many of whom can perform magic
- A character who is able to use [extra-sensory perception](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/powerlisting/images/b/bd/Toph_seeing_thru_metal.gif/revision/latest?cb=20130630124303) to "see" the world around her
- [Love potions](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Love_Potion_8) and [purchasable spells](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Amulet_Quest)

---

There are also some "[magitek](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Magitek)" elements that cross over into science fantasy;

- Vehicles (tanks, ships/submarines, flying ships) that are powered by magic-users
- Power stations that are powered by magic

Comment: When are there love potions and purchasable spells?

Comment: @roguejedi - http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Love_Potion_8

Comment: I'm not sure how canon that is, but ok. What about purchasable spells, though?

Comment: @RogueJedi - You can pick up chi scrolls in the game for gold.